# Storing and displaying image resources strategy

Tags: android, image, resources

As we know it there are [several screen layout out there](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on various android devices. Now, my question is, what's the best solution for displaying image on screen (full sized image) on that various device?

Should I (this is several strategy I have in mind right now):

- resize every images for that target device? (with the cost of resizing it and lost of quality on larger device)
- create several images for all or several common screen size? (with larger download size)
- create core application and let them download images appropriate to that screen size (that means, I have to prepare hosting of those images)
- something I don't know yet...

So, if you guys have experience in this kind of situation, your recommendation is greatly appreciated.

Update: My application will have several (20-30) images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented ( http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ) and answered quite a few times already I believe.

Create different images for the different screen resolution (store in drawable, drawable-hdpi... accordingly).

You can also define different layouts for different screen sizes (although to display full screen images, it does not sound like you need that).